# How to call models in Laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

So, in L5 I created folder like `app/Models/Blog` where is file `Posts.php` which looks like:

```
<?php namespace App\Models\Blog;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Posts extends Model {
    protected $table = 'posts';
}
```

After it I executed `composer dump` and then in my controller:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Models\Blog\Posts as Posts;

class BlogController extends Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        $post = Posts::all()->toArray();

        dd($post);
    }
}
```

It throws me an error:

```
FatalErrorException in BlogController.php line 14: Class 'Models\Blog\Posts' not found
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try **changing** this:

```
use Models\Blog\Posts as Posts;
```

**To this:**

```
use App\Models\Blog\Posts;
```

Comment: oh, my inattention... Thanks

Comment: can you explain why does Laravel no need to `include` model file although they located at different directory

Answer (score 1):

In Laravel 5.2 it's just:

```
use App\Blog;
```

or

```
use App\Blog\Posts;
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the following

```
class Posts extends Model {
```

to

```
class Posts extends \Eloquent {
```

Comment: I'm sorry. I read it to fast. You forgot the namespace before the path (default is app).

Answer (score 0):

You need to check two points :

1. the `namespace` have to be in first
2. the using must be `use App\Models\Blog` in your case

Like this :

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\Blog;

class BlogController extends Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        $post = Posts::all()->toArray();

        dd($post);
    }
}
```

(tested with Laravel 5.4)